# Find values through multiple Excel files and write the whole row to a text file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am currently trying to create an .vbs script file where you can find multiple values through multiple excel files and then (if results were found) write the entire row to an .txt file.

[image]

How to extract the value data of the entire row where the value has been found in string format in order to write it to the text file?

This is my progress so far:

```
sOutputPath = "C:\output.txt"
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oOutputFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(sOutputPath, True)
Dim aFiles() 'Array of excel file paths
Dim aSearch() 'Array of search values

fMain()
Sub fMain()

oExcel.visible = False
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

'Set search values (this is the way I prefer it for now, all strings)
aSearch(0) = "Test"
aSearch(1) = "1236xy"

'Set excel paths
aFiles(0) = "C:\workbook1.xlsx"
aFiles(1) = "C:\workbook2.xlsx"
aFiles(2) = "C:\workbook3.xlsx"

For Each file in aFiles
    Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file, , true) 'Open Read-Only
    Set oWorksheet = oWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'Always the first sheet
    Set oRange = oWorksheet.UsedRange 'Search everywhere

    For Each entry in aSearch
        Set oTarget = oRange.Find(entry)
        If Not oTarget Is Nothing Then
            oOutputFile.WriteLine(file) 'Write the file path as a title if a value was found within that file
             'Here I became stuck and don't know how to proceed, I need the write the whole row where the cell containing the value was found to the oOutputFile
        End If
    Next
    On Error Resume Next
    oWorkbook.Saved = True
    oWorkbook.Close(False)
Next

oOutputFile.Close
oExcel.Quit
End Sub
wScript.Quit
```